# Function that checks if a float is 3 digit

Tags: python

Create a function that checks if a number is a three digit number.

For example:

5.67 will be considered a three digit number
3.01 will be considered a three digit number
3.00 will not be cosidered a three digit number
0.123 will be cosidered a three digit number
Call your function: three_digit()

I have already done some work[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV3Ay.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code here rather than images or screenshots

Comment: You're cheating.  The code you posted checks to see if the number is odd.  Your spec is strange, but you can give it a shot.

Comment: And what about 58,900.0?  Is that three digits?  What about 0.000876?

Comment: You are going to run into some floating point representation issues. Some decimal values are not possible to represent exactly in floats. So they will show up such as 2.30000000000012. That will affect how you measure 3 digits.

Comment: @Tim Roberts how am I cheating?

Comment: You said you had done some work, but you had done no work at all.  You copied an "is this number odd" function and changed the function name.

Comment: You still haven't completely specified the problem, how can we know if there's a simpler solution?

Comment: Leave it guys ima figure it out I think I get it

Answer (score 0):

this is works:

```
def three_digit(num):
    if len(str(num).replace(".","").lstrip('0'))==3:
        return "YES"
    else:
        return "NO"
        
print(three_digit(1.234))
```

Comment: Close, but your code fails for 0.123.  You can just .strip('0').  That was going to be my answer.

Comment: You asked for us to do your homework without making any effort on your own.  That's cheating.

Comment: `lstrip` isn't sufficient because it still considers trailing zeros.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I think lstrip also removes trailing characters (from the left).

Comment: @TechySharnav trailing characters are on the right by definition, not the left.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Okay. But by converting the float to str, it removes the trailing zeros on the right. Like `str(5.670000000)` returns `'5.67'`

Comment: @TechySharnav see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987).  And consider the example that Tim Roberts gave of 58900.